# Move git directory from one LFS-enabled repo to another (also LFS)

Tags: git, git-lfs

We are looking to move a specific directory from one git repository to another. I found [these instructions](http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/), which went well until the point of the pull from the remote branch; it appears that having files on both sides that are tracked by git-lfs complicates the process somewhat.

I tried this both directly between my local clones, as well as doing the filter-branch on a branch and pushing it to the main server (VSTS). In both cases the smudge filter failed, saying it couldn't find the LFS-tracked file; with the VSTS remote the error logged is a 404.

I'd like to keep these files as LFS tracked in the destination, whether the move is done using the local clones direct or involves the server. Are there any additional commands/switches or preparation steps that will allow this?

Comment: Apologies for the title; I'd replaced my search terms with "Move git directory from one LFS-enabled repo to another (also LFS)" but it appears the browser on this device reverted the change, and now I can't seem to edit it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Upvoted the other answer for the hint in the right direction, though my newbie rep won't have it show.)

The key here seems to have been `git lfs fetch --all` before branching off and running `filter-branch`, move and commit as described in the article. It looks like LFS isn't intended to work between local clones; reversing the procedure so as to `push` to the destination clone also resulted in an error, but it did work when pushing to the remote server for the destination repo.

From there, a fetch into the destination clone and merge with `--allow-unrelated-histories` looks to have given us what we were after.

Answer (score 4):

According to [repository clone times-out lfs files cannot be retrieved #1181](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1181#issuecomment-214435967)

> In both cases the smudge filter failed, saying it couldn't find the LFS-tracked file; with the VSTS remote the error logged is a 404.

It means that the files do not exist on the server. You can try to find a local clone of that repository that has it, and run `git lfs push REMOTE_NAME --all`.

And you may need to execute `git lfs fetch --all` to download all LFS-tracked files before you push them to your new Git repository.

Comment: The key here was `git lfs fetch --all`.

Comment: Is this what you need?

Comment: More detail in separate answer.

Comment: Related step-to-step answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62911723/2538363). But essentially - as described in this answer - executing `git lfs push` to the destination repo fixes errors for missing `lfs` files that can occur during the `pull --allow-unrelated-histories` step. `lfs` files are handled separately and should be handled separately also during a migration.

Comment: This was the breadcrumb that helped me move a repo with LFS between two workspaces on BitBucket, which is not currently supported via their Transfer Repository function. I did a `git clone <OLDURL>`, then cd into it, then `git lfs fetch --all`, then `git remote -v` to confirm source location, then `git remote set-url origin <NEWURL>`, then `git ls-remote` to confirm, then `git push origin --all`, then `git lfs push origin --all`.

Answer (score 0):

for my the easiest way was to fork the repository (it means on the server side)

Answer (score 0):

Turning @djdanlib 's comment into an answer (with some clarification) as this was the most helpful answer for me and my team during a transition from GitHub to ADO.

- `git clone <OLDURL>` (if you don't already have it locally)
- `git remote -v` (check that you are pointed to the old repo)
- `git lfs fetch --all` (forces the download of all the LFS files)
- `git remote set-url origin <NEWURL>` (you are now pointing to your new repo)
- `git remote -v` or `git ls-remote` (double-check you are pointing to the new URL)
- `git push origin --all` (pushes all branches to the repo)
- `git lfs push origin --all` (pushes all LFS files to the repo)