# How can you migrate between Git LFS Repositories

Tags: git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

I have an existing repo with git-lfs enabled (at GitHub) and 1GB of files in it. For bandwidth reasons, I want to stop using GitHub and start using a LFS repo hosted on the corporate network. Does anyone know how to migrate *between* git lfs repos?

I could convert to "a normal repo without git-lfs" and then back to git-lfs, but there must be a way to just do this without rewriting history and just copying over the files right?

Thanks!

Comment: have you read https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.19/admin/installation/migrating-to-a-different-git-large-file-storage-server?

Comment: Nice I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 6):

(from [The Github Enterprise installation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.19/admin/installation/migrating-to-a-different-git-large-file-storage-server), kudo's for pointing that out [@Polygnome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1360803/polygnome))

1. Add a second remote

```
$ git remote add NEW-REMOTE https://NEW-REMOTE-HOSTNAME/path/to/repo
 
$ git lfs env
> git-lfs/1.1.0 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.5.1; git 94d356c)
> git version 2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)
 
> Endpoint=https://GITHUB-ENTERPRISE-HOST/path/to/repo/info/lfs (auth=basic)
> Endpoint (NEW-REMOTE)=https://NEW-REMOTE-HOSTNAME/path/to/repo/info/lfs (auth=none)
```

2. Fetch from old remote

```
$ git lfs fetch origin --all
> Scanning for all objects ever referenced...
> ✔ 16 objects found
> Fetching objects...
> Git LFS: (16 of 16 files) 48.71 MB / 48.85 MB
```

3. Push to new remote

```
$ git lfs push NEW-REMOTE --all
> Scanning for all objects ever referenced...
> ✔ 16 objects found
> Pushing objects...
> Git LFS: (16 of 16 files) 48.00 MB / 48.85 MB, 879.10 KB skipped
```

4. Make new remote the default by editing `.lfsconfig` and make it the default for everybody

Comment: For those interested I was changing the git-lfs Endpoint to a new one in a repo I had checked out and that was already using lfs. To do this I did step 4 first and then ran: 'git lfs push origin main --all'

This seems to have done the job for me.