# Push mirrored repo to new source with large file storage

Tags: github, git-lfs

I am attempting to do is migrate a repo from one source (bitbucket) to another (github.) I am aware the normal process is to do a `git clone -mirror <original repo address>`, add a new remote origin to the new source, then push to the new source. This works fine with smaller repos.

However, with one repo I get blocked by git pre-commit hooks. After some testing, I'm fairly certain that it is a lfs issue with github.

What is the step by step process around this?

edit: the important part is to also carry over all the branches + tags with the commit history.

Comment: [Probable duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62900161/1256452)

Comment: This probably duplicate did not resolve the issue.